# Error message while trying to install the mase plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed agent tool3 on my eclipse and proceeds to install the MASE plug in for analysis and design. I really need the plug in for a design and analysis but unfortunately, after the installation of the agent tool3 the next step towards installing the MASE pugin I got this error message below.

Plug-in org.eclipse.epf.authoring.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.epf.authoring.ui.views.LibraryView.

I have done everything within my knowledge but cant seem to get a solution. below are pictures of the errors

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: The version is eclipse mars 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have this class loading errors because agentTool III and MaSE are for Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede). Usually eclipse tools have open range for dependencies to prevent blocking users from installing it into newer Eclipse release. It works sometimes, if tools do not use restricted/none public API which tends to have many changes between major Eclipse releases.

I cannot see details on your screenshots but it feels like some classes were removed/refactored in Eclipse Mars since Ganymede release.

Comment: ok, so I should uninstall the mars and try installing with Ganymede?

Comment: that's correct, try to install it with clean Eclipse Ganymede.